# Equality of Ratio of Gamma Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, factorial, gamma-function, ratio

I recently encountered the following, but I am unsure under what conditions for $n$ it is true:

$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-2)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}=\frac{1}{(\frac{n}{2}-2)(\frac{n}{2}-1)}$$

I understand how this would be true whenever $n$ is an even integer that's greater than 4 (since I can apply factorial properties), but is it true in general for a real number $n$?  If so, is there a general way to determine the value of the ratio of any two gamma functions?

Comment: The $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,-1,-2,-3,...\}$. So, you can do $\Gamma(n/2)=(n/2-1)\Gamma(n/2-1)=(n/2-1)(n/2-2)\Gamma(n/2-2)$.

Comment: The Wikipedia article explains how to define the gamma function with an integral so that it satisfies the formula for $x>0$.  For other values, you need complex analysis, which I gather you haven't studied yet.

Comment: Let me take that back.  You could use the functional equation $\Gamma (x+1)=x\Gamma (x)$ to define the gamma function for non-integral negative $x$